# Fourier Transform of a Step Function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to obtain the form of a sinc function that I know I'm supposed to get in *Mathematica*. I'm doing this because I intend to do a lot with Fourier transforms (FT) and I'd like to know I'm not missing constants or something of the like.

For example, consider:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    A && -\frac{a}{2} ≤ x ≤ \frac{a}{2}\\
    0 && \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

Employing the following:

```
FourierTransform[UnitStep[a/2 + x] UnitStep[a/2 - x], x, k, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

It gives:   `(2 Sin[(a k)/2] UnitStep[a])/k`

Is this *Mathematica*'s way of giving the sinc function? I guess I was expecting something more like `(2 Sin[(a k)/2])/(k a)`. I know there are different parameters that can be used, but none of them have given the form I was expecting.

When I try to do the FT directly as an integral:

```
Integrate[A Exp[-I k x], {k, -a/2, a/2}]
```

It gives: `(2 A Sin[(a x)/2])/x`

Are these the same? I was expecting something that would lead to $\rm{sinc}[k a/2]$. I have not found previous questions that can help, and the documentation in *Mathematica* (version 8) also has not helped either.

Comment: Since 'a' could be negative, that UnitStep factor is appropriate. To be rid of it add Assumptions->a>0 to the FT.

Comment: Thanks, I added that and the result now look like this: (2 Sin[(a k)/2])/k

Comment: That appears to be equivalent to Sinc[a*k/2]/a, which means it is probably fine (I am not willing to wade through the parameter specs to prove this though).

Comment: `Reduce[(2 Sin[(a k)/2])/k == Sinc[a*k/2]/a]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Mathematica there is a designated function for this, [**UnitBox**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitBox.html),

```
PiecewiseExpand[UnitBox[x]]
```

[image]

which [**gives expected result**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0e7rsyye-dtktd) without assumptions:

```
FourierTransform[UnitBox[x/a], x, k, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

> Abs[a] Sinc[(a k)/2]

There is actually a set of designated functions:

```
FourierTransform[UnitTriangle[x/a], x, t, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
```

> Abs[a] Sinc[(a t)/2]^2

```
FourierSinCoefficient[#[x], x, n, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi}] & /@ 
{TriangleWave, SawtoothWave, SquareWave}
```

[image]

Comment: nice, I didn't know about `UnitBox`... I've always defined my own `rect` function with the above piecewise definition

Answer (score 8):

There is no inconsistency here. If you assume `a` to be positive, as Daniel mentioned, you get the same answer:

```
FourierTransform[UnitStep[a/2 + x] UnitStep[a/2 - x], x, k, 
    FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
(* (2 Sin[(a k)/2])/k *)

Integrate[UnitStep[a/2 + x] UnitStep[a/2 - x] Exp[-I k x], 
    {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
(* (2 Sin[(a k)/2])/k *)
```

Note that:

$$ \frac{2\sin(a k/2)}{k} = \frac{a \sin (ak/2)}{ak/2} = a \text{sinc}(ak/2)$$